# Don't want my own artifacts in Nexus to be public

Tags: maven, nexus

In my Nexus, my own project is under a hosted repository "Snapshots". I have to assign this repository to "public repositories"; otherwise, I can't compile my own project with mvn. This would be the error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project bword: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.bbword.core:bword:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.bbword.core:tts-app:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in nexus (http://www.bbword.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Certainly, I don't want my own project under public repositories on the Internet. Which configuration might I be wrong?

This is my settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://www.bbword.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>bbword</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Edited: attached a picture for better illustration.
[image]

My project is under "The Snapshots".

Edited: New attached for details.

[image]

Comment: So use a local Nexus to store such things or make a separate group within Nexus which is not public accessible.

Comment: @khmarbaise, please see the picture for current status. What "separate group" do you mean and how can I make it? The "Snapshots" isn't currently under "Public repository".

Comment: Make a new repository group See here: https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/config-sect-new-repo.html and add the snapshot to that group...

Comment: @khmarbaise, I created a Private Repository and put it under this group. However, it seems private group doesn't allow remote access. Please see the new photo. Is that what you meant by "make a separate group which is not public accessible"?

Answer (score 0):

You have different places to control what is *publicly accessible from the internet*:

- you can tell nexus that the repository is private but maven will not be able to use it
- you can tell nexus that the repository is public and hide your own nexus from the internet.

When you configure you own local nexus, what is public is what nexus shows on its own server. That does not mean that is is automatically uploaded to maven central or any other public nexus server.

But if it is your own nexus, you have no reason to make the server itself accessible from the internet and the firewall (or your ISP router) should simply not allow external call to end here. That will be enough for you own project not to lie *under public repositories on the Internet*.

Comment: How to NOT make my own nexus accessible externally?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing how the machine hosting the nexus is connected to internet. You won't use same solutions in a corporate network, at home, or on a Infrastructure As A Service cloud virtual machine...

Answer (score 0):

There is at least 2 way of doing this. Both require some admin access.

The applicative way: You create a new hosted repository and protect it with credential Here a post that describe how :(http://minibiti.blogspot.ca/2012/03/private-repositories-in-sonatype-nexus.html) 
You may even disable the UI for that repository.

The network way: 
You need to have access to your nexus but isolate it from the internet. Of course if you do this Do not proxy the central repository nor using it as a mirror.

Also the post for the first solution suggest that you put your password in plain text. I don't like this. Take a look at this post for the maven encryption https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html

EDIT:
Here how to add credential to settings.xml

```
<repository>
                    <id>ID</id>
                    <name>name</name>
                    <url>URL</url>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                </repository>

<server>
            <id>ID</id>
            <username>USER</username>
            <password>PASSWORD</password>
        </server>
```

Comment: I followed the first solution by restricting anonymous to public repositories read only and put my own project in a non-public (non private either) hosted repository. However, I can still browse it from Internet: http://www.bombword.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/bombword/core/bword. Why it is that?

Comment: the link return me a 401 Access denied, Also http://www.bombword.com:8081/nexus/#welcome , I cannot see any repository in there

Comment: that's true. I logged out and can't access it any more without login first. But the other problem is that I can't access my own project through maven. Using mvn compile, I received this: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project bword: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.bombword.core:bword:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: T

Comment: You need to add that repository to your settings.xml (or CI like jenkins settings.xml) Also provide proper credential to that repository

Comment: I configured that two pieces of information in the <mirror> and <server> tags of my settings.xml, but can't receive it. When it is in the public repositories in my nexus, it can access.

Comment: You need to add a repository, not a mirror i updated the answer. the ID must match between the server and the repository. Be careful a bad mirrror settings might block you from downloading the artefact Also please take not of <snapshot> and <release> tag, you can put both of them to enable